# How to remove or edit parts of string from absolute path

Tags: tomcat, path

I want to find $CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE on many servers running Tomcat6. Finding tomcat installs via yum and rpm is straightforward. For others, I am using find for catalina.sh. Output varies but looks something like this:

/opt/apache6-version-release/bin/catalina.sh

or any path like:

/usr/tomcat/bin/apps/apache6-version-version/bin/catalina.sh

You get the idea. I want to be able to grab just the ouput path up to /dir/dir/apache6-version-release". I am using apache-version to account for all the releases. These paths are to used in a script I need to create to check for security settings. So I am looking for a way to remove the trailing /bin/catalina.sh from the path. I see /bin directory being used in some of the parent directory paths so I want to be cautious to remove only the trailing /bin/catalina.sh. I used cut and awk for a character count. This seems to work, but was wondering how this could be done using the string or another way.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dirname $(dirname /usr/tomcat/bin/apps/apache6-version-version/bin/catalina.sh)
```